# Como enviar uma notificação mesmo com a pagina da aplicação fechada?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Quero enviar notificações da minha aplicação utilizando a api notification do chrome mesmo quando o usuário estiver com a pagina fechada.
Vi essa funcionalidade em diversos blogs, como por exemplo o [tecnoblog.net](http://tecnoblog.net).

Ela funciona da seguinte forma: Usuário acessa o site pela primeira vez, chrome solicita a autorização para enviar notificações, então mesmo que você esteja com a pagina do blog fechadao chrome notifica quando tem um post novo.

Eu já trabalho com a api notification, mas não consigo fazer isso, já procurei na documentação e não obtive sucesso.

Você saberia?

Comment: já que tem como alvo o Google Chrome, já tentou utilizar à [Service API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API)?

Comment: http://imasters.com.br/artigo/19377/javascript/criando-extensao-para-google-chrome/

Comment: @TobyMosque muito interessante Service API, talvez ele funcione extamente para que eu quero. 
Vou testar e posto aqui o resultado.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert não era bem isso que eu tinha em mente, mas é uma alternativa elegante. Se não conseguir o que eu quero vou tentar fazer uma extenção. Obrigado.